# java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, deployment

Is there a way to load a custom HttpServlet to GAE? I uploaded a project that included an HttpServlet in the .server package and added it to the web.xml...

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>gwtone.server.TestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/tester/greet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Is there something else I am missing, or is it not possible?

--------EDIT--------

some things that appear when i init my server, which im not used to seeing...

```
Jan 22, 2012 4:23:44 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Jan 22, 2012 4:23:44 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed E:\Program Files\eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32-x86_64\Workspace\gwtone\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Jan 22, 2012 4:23:44 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed E:\Program Files\eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32-x86_64\Workspace\gwtone\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Jan 21, 2012 10:23:44 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
Jan 21, 2012 10:23:44 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
```

and here is what shows when it crashes..

```
WARNING: Error for /tester/greet
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 14 in method gwtone.server.TestServlet.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V at offset 0
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

EDIT #2

```
package gwtone.server;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

public TestServlet(){}

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("0");
    try {
        System.out.println("1");
        resp.getWriter().println("IT WORKED");
        resp.getWriter().flush();
        System.out.println("2");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("3");
}
}
```

Comment: The configuration provided looks ok. Can you provide log or error message?

Comment: VerifyError probably refer to invalid bytecode. Verify that the Servlet class is free of compilation error (more specifically the doGet method or the constructor). If possible, post the Servlet code.

Comment: servlet code posted in edit #2, and it doesnt print the 0,1,2,3 it just responds with status 500. also, i work with GWT at work, but this is the first solo project with having to set up eclipse and stuff too.

Comment: Seems to be a JDK 1.7 issue : https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!msg/apps/GCwVC-Vizpk/7KT5qna4pU4J

Comment: yeah, i tried like 12 different things. Can you not use indigo with GWT or something?

Comment: This error keeps biting me and I also use GAE! it occurs when I call some static methods that return a BlobKey. Here's a Gist with byte code https://gist.github.com/ZiglioNZ/bd1d7d424727b3f26c64

Answer (score 25, accepted):

GAE uses Java 1.6, but you've compiled the code with Java 1.7. You need to recompile with Java 1.6. As per the comments, you're using Eclipse; you can set the Java compiler level in *Java > Compiler* section of project's properties.

[image]

Comment: thanks, i tried to use 1.6 as my default via windows control panel, but i guess i had to change it in eclipse...

Comment: and my default jdk for eclipse is changed to 1.6, thanks again

Comment: 1.6 is deprecated by GAE now

Answer (score 35):

As BalusC pointed out, one solution to the problem is to just use JDK6.

Another solution, if you want to stay with JDK7, would be to use "**-XX:-UseSplitVerifier**" as an argument for the VM.
Go to

**Window → Preferences → Java → Installed JREs → Edit... → Default VM arguments**

and add it there.

[image: Installed JREs]
[image: JRE Definition]

Comment: this is a silly solution: 1. UseSplitVerifier is being deprecated by Oracle (if I find the link to that, I'll post it) 2. it may solve the development server, what about GAE's production server?

Comment: more on the UserSplitVerifier option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253173/how-safe-is-it-to-use-xx-usesplitverifier

Answer (score 1):

Using -XX:-UseSplitVerifier is a temporary solution. Now java uses the previous version of the bytecode verifier which tolerates this bad or missing stackmap frames. Java8 doesnt support this option.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by setting Eclipse Mars / Project properties / Java compiler :

- Compiler compliance level to 1.7 (as I don't have 1.6 anymore)
- Generated .class files compatibility : **1.6**
- Source compatibility : **1.6**

as I didn't have 1.7 specific code :-)

Server Ubuntu + Tomcat 7.0.52 on JVM 1.7.0_85-b01
Dev Eclipse Mars on JDK 7u55