# Starting Up Tomcat Server w/ Spring in org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, apache, tomcat

I am currently trying to get Tomcat up and running. It looks as though something with Spring is going wrong. Searching around, it seems as though there is something wrong with my common-* files or something of the sort. However, nothing I've found seems very promising.

A few things that I have understood is that I might be missing a .jar file in my WEB-INF/ folder, or that I don't have the correct DBCP version. Anything else is beyond me.

```
May 07, 2012 5:48:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 249 in method com.expertwebdev.tribe.auth.AuthServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails; at offset 0
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:930)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:903)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

May 07, 2012 5:48:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 07, 2012 5:48:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/utero] startup failed due to previous errors
May 07, 2012 5:48:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
May 07, 2012 5:48:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 07, 2012 5:48:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 07, 2012 5:48:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8901 ms
```

Comment: By any chance are you running Java 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to run code compiled with java 6 (spring framework's) on a JRE 7 JVM.

The [VerifyError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/VerifyError.html) is evident that the class `Class` expects to find some native method that doesn't exist in the JRE `getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)`. So, it's a contradiction between the actual class `Class` that was invoked by spring framework jars and the available native methods in the JVM.

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958267/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame) which shows a similar problem in the same class `Class` method. That was also the problem there.

In short, check that your spring jars are compatible with the JRE you use.

Comment: With a little bit of reworking my IDE, I was able to install and use JDK 6 and it is working smooth now. Thank you!