# Grails application running fine in localhost, but fails on Tomcat server?

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-security

I have a **Grails 1.3.7** application compiled with **JDK 1.7** that I'm trying to run on **Tomcat 6.0.33.0**. The application runs fine with `grails run-app` locally, but when I deploy the WAR file to the server, I'm getting the following exception when Tomcat's trying to configure Spring security:

> Configuring Spring Security ...
>   context.ContextLoader Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 26 in method org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.(Lorg/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler;)

I have no idea where to even begin debugging this issue. I already did `grails clean` and I also tried pulling a fresh copy of the repo and starting from there, but no dice. Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: Try adding  -XX:-UseSplitVerifier to your VM arguments. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958267/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame

Comment: Does tomcat runs on the same java version that the project was compiled (1.7) ?

Comment: enterlezi: It does. I have a sneaking suspicion that Grails 1.3.7 doesn't like JDK 1.7 for some reason, but I've yet to test that theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've pinned down the issue to **Grails 1.3.7** not working well with **Java 1.7**. I updated the project to **Grails 2.0.4** and everything is working fine now.