# com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 404

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt, error-handling

I have the following error 404 in google GWT:
"Google App Engine Java and GWT Application Development Code."

The program called connactr.

```
[ERROR] [connectr] - com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 404 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 NOT_FOUND</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /connectr/loginService. Reason:
<pre>    NOT_FOUND</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>                                                                   
</body>
</html>
```

my web.xml:

```
  <!-- ===================== Login Service ===================== -->
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>loginService</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.metadot.book.connectr.server.LoginServiceImpl</servlet-class>

  </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>loginService</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/connectr/loginService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The exception given by Jetty:

```
   java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 188 in method     com.metadot.book.connectr.server.servlets.LoginFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletReques
t;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V at offset 8
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:92)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:197)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:241)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:148)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
```

The have the relevant impl class.
Any idea what is wrong?

Thank you in advance,
Idan.

Answer (score 0):

404 error information you have shared is bit too less. You need to share exact exception thrown by gwt on server side to get clear answer.

1. First up check if you have the relevant impl class and whether it is in claaspath I.e jetty should load it.
2. Check whether it is instantiated when rpc call from client is made. Whether your rpc service invocation is reaching the right service impl.
3. Check and solve any exception service impl is throwing on server side.

Comment: Looks more or less a coding/compiling issue - check whether this is same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958267/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame