# Sudden "java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target"

Tags: jsp, jpa, server, publish

I had an error today on my GlassFish 3.1 server when publishing.
I tried my best with my internet researcher skils to resolved it but after hours I decided to post here :

So I had to reinstall my server GlassFish 3.1 and here is what I end with :

```
2016-10-13T21:00:04.610+0900|Grave: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:249)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:465)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:222)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:234)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 32
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/tm/entities/Education._persistence_initialize_School_vh()V @4: ifnonnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab4 00d0 c700 1c2a bb01 2259 2ab4 0110
    0000010: b701 24b5 00d0 2ab4 00d0 04b9 0128 0200
    0000020: b1                                     

    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.TypeUtil.getMethod(TypeUtil.java:399)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.MethodDescriptor.getMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:314)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.convertEJBMethodPermissions(EJBSecurityManager.java:550)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.loadPolicyConfiguration(EJBSecurityManager.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.initialize(EJBSecurityManager.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.<init>(EJBSecurityManager.java:190)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.factory.EJBSecurityManagerFactory.createManager(EJBSecurityManagerFactory.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:233)
    ... 32 more
```

(and 4 more "Expected stackmap frame at this location")

So all my project use JDK 1.7 :
 - I have configured the server this way
 - My project is configured this way

I have tried to :
 - Reinstall properly the server
 - Windows>Preferences>Installed JRE use "-XX:-UseSplitVerifier" and/or "-noverify"

Pages looked at :

> [java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target JDK 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122890/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame-at-branch-target-jdk-1-7)
>
> [java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958267/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame)
>
> https://dzone.com/articles/javalangverifyerror-expecting

Thanks !

Comment: What is this class "Education" ? and what about this field/method _persistence_initialize_School_vh ? The result of bytecode enhancement?

Comment: `Education` is a persistence class (marketed with `@Entity`) and method `_persistence_initialize_School_vh` is indeed generated by the bytecode

Comment: So the bytecode enhancement process has a problem with the JDK in use etc

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally migrat to Glassfish 4 and use Java 1.8 in my project.

I had some trouble creating the JDBC Pool Connection since there is a bug in Glassfish 4.0 but internet was here to help me.